# Covariance and vector

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I was wondering if there is any significance of multiplying a covariance-variance matrix by either a vector or matrix? I've tried searching around on the internet but haven't been able to find any real information.

Comment: If you diagonalize the co-variance matrix you can do principle component analysis.  And I have had times when it has been handy to turn a co-variance matrix into a correlation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

When working with confidence intervals. Sometimes you have to multiply the $X(X'X)X'$ bythe MSE in order to get the variance covariance matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. If $\Sigma$ is the variance covariance vector of $Y=(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)^T$ and $l$ is a $n\times 1$ vector then $\Sigma l$ is the cross-covariance matrix of $Y$ with $l^TY$ i.e., $\Sigma l = \text{Cov}(Y,l^TY)$ similarly for a $n \times p$ matrix $A$, $\Sigma A = \text{Cov}(Y,A^TY).$